# What is the use of currying in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, currying

Theortically I know what currying is.

Can anyone tell me the practical use of currying in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion what make currying interesting is that it makes easier to compose functions using a pointfree programming style.

You can find more information in this [book chapter](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/ch4.html).

Comment: https://medium.com/@tejassavaliya/what-is-currying-in-javascript-25fcfff413b4

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same as in every other language,  e.g. easy partial application:

```
function curriedAdd(a) {
    return function(b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

var xs = [1, 2, 3].map(curriedAdd(2));
```

Compare this to an uncurried approach:

```
function add(a,b) {
    return a + b;
}

var xs = [1,2,3].map(add.bind(null, 2));
```

There's nothing super special about JS in this regard.

Comment: I still didnt get you!!!

Comment: @RohitGoyal let me expand

Comment: Isn't `.bind` still a _"curried approach"_? Wouldn't the _"uncurried approach"_ be `function (e) {return add(2, e);}`